# update app terminate without showing contacts permission in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have used the contact permission to read the contacts from phone book in swift 5. I have updated to apple store. But When it update in IOS device, It dose not showing the contact permission rather it app is terminated. But if I uninstall app & then install again from play store it show the contact permission.It is working fine.But user update apps does not show 
the contact permission & app terminated when user navigate to view controller

Heere is my info.plist ...

[image]

1. Check the access permission in viewDidLoad of  viewController

   ```
   if (CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) ==  .authorized ){

       do{
           try  fetch_contacts()
       }catch let error {
           print("error-->",error)
       }
   } else {

   CNContactStore().requestAccess(for: .contacts, completionHandler: { granted, error in
      if (granted){
               //access allowed

           else{
               //access denied

               // Create Alert
               let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Contact", message: "Please Allow Contacts Access for this app", preferredStyle: .alert)

               // Add "OK" Button to alert, pressing it will bring you to the settings app
               alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
                   UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)!)
               }))
               // Show the alert with animation
               self.present(alert, animated: true)
           }
       })
   }
   ```
2. here is my method **fetch_contacts()** by which I have fetch data from phone book.

   ```
   func fetch_contacts(){
     let contactStore = CNContactStore()
      var contacts = [CNContact]()
      let keys = [
       CNContactFormatter.descriptorForRequiredKeys(for: .fullName),
       CNContactPhoneNumbersKey,
       CNContactEmailAddressesKey
       ] as [Any]
     let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as! [CNKeyDescriptor])
      do {
         try contactStore.enumerateContacts(with: request){
           (contact, stop) in
           // Array containing all unified contacts from everywhere
           contacts.append(contact)
           for phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers {
               if let number = phoneNumber.value as? CNPhoneNumber, let label = phoneNumber.label {
                   let localizedLabel = CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>.localizedString(forLabel: label)

                   var name = contact.givenName;


                   let charsToRemove: Set<Character> = Set("()+-".characters)
                   let newNumberCharacters = String(number.stringValue.characters.filter { !charsToRemove.contains($0) })
                   // print("newNumberCharacters--",newNumberCharacters)

                   var number = newNumberCharacters.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
                   //  a.suffix(4)
                   //print(number.suffix(11))
                   let last11 = String(number.characters.suffix(11))

                   self.arrRes += [
                       ["name":name as Any,"number":last11 as Any]
                   ]

                   // self.arrRes.append(a);
                   /*
                    statusList = [
                    ["desc":"--Select--" as AnyObject,"type":"--Select--" as AnyObject]
                    ]
                    **/
               }
           }
       }
       // print(contacts)
       //print("arrRes******>",arrRes)
       if(self.arrRes.count>0){
           self.tableView.reloadData()
       }

   } catch {
       print("unable to fetch contacts")
   }
   }
   ```

   I have already two time updated app. It won't solve the problem. When i go to viewController app is terminated.

Please help me what is the wrong with the code

Comment: What happens when you install an old version of your app from the store and then run the upgraded version from Xcode or TestFlight?  Which line is it crashing on? What is the exception message?

Comment: @Paulw11 hello sir I did not test like that. I am checking

Comment: @Paulw11 sir, In my device it running fine. But when existing app which install in user device does not ruining . But i don't find the message why it is terminated. But if user uninstall app then install it again it is working fine.

Comment: You need to identify why and where it is crashing.  It may be nothing to do with contact permissions.  Have you checked in App Store Connect or Xcode for crash logs?